# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I have a weird problem with python passing a list as parameter to a function. Here is the code:

```
def foobar(depth, top, bottom, n=len(listTop)):
    print dir(top)
    print top.append("hi")
    if depth > 0:
        exit()
    foobar(depth+1, top.append(listTop[i]), bottom.append(listBottom[i]))

top = bottom = []
foobar(0, top, bottom)
```

It says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'", because top is None in foobar although dir(top) prints a full attribute and method list of a type list.
So whats wrong? I just wanted to pass two lists as parameters to this recursive function.

Comment: In your example, `top` and `bottom` refer to the same list, and this will lead to (maybe) unexpected results in your code. (`t = b = [];t.append(1);print b`)

Comment: This wasn't the reason of the described problem, but it solved another one i didn't noticed yet. So thanks either way.

Comment: Glad it helped. And that's why I didn't post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You pass in the *result* of `top.append()` to your function. `top.append()` returns None:

```
>>> [].append(0) is None
True
```

You need to call `.append()` separately, then pass in just `top`:

```
top.append(listTop[i])
bottom.append(listBottom[i])
foobar(depth+1, top, bottom)
```

Note that the `n=len(listTop)` argument in the function is both redundant and only ever executed once, namely when you *create* the function. It won't be evaluated each time you call the function. You can omit it safely from the version you posted here in any case.

Comment: Yeah, i thought it would return the list... so thanks, that solved it. That n is only set on creation is deliberate.

Answer (score 2):

`top.append(listTop[i])` works in place and returns `None`