# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' no matter what

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm (trying to) parsing outputs from a software used by my research group and, so far, I was able to iterate, line by line, the lists I need (ok, there is this little annoying empty list [] at the end of the loop). The real problem starts when I try to append the lists I got in each iteration to a big list (a list of lists) so I can work with it outside the loop.

So far, here is the code:

```
vdf_file_path = "/home/henrique/Coding/Python/VEDA2XLSX/nq1a.vdf"

vdf_big_list = []
vdf_s_lines_string = """ """

with open(vdf_file_path, "r") as vdf_all_input_lines:
    for vdf_line in vdf_all_input_lines.readlines()[4:]:
        if "Frequencies" in vdf_line:
            break
        else:
            vdf_s_line_fixed = vdf_line.strip()
            vdf_s_lines_list = list(filter(None,vdf_s_line_fixed.split(" ")))
            vdf_big_list = vdf_big_list.append(vdf_s_lines_list)
```

(forgive me for the messy code, I'm still learning)

Then I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/henrique/Coding/Python/VEDA2XLSX/importvdf.py", line 12, in <module>
    vdf_big_list = vdf_big_list.append(vdf_s_lines_list)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Despite reading the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555551/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-append) and trying several approaches, I'm still unable to understand what is the problem and fix it.

Any advices?

**Data Sample**:

```
abbreviation of: e:\documents\yyyy\yyyyyy-yyyyyy\camb3lyp\dmso\veda\nq1a.ved
IR spectrum from file: e:\Documents\yyyyyyy\yyyyyyyyy-yyyyyyyy\CAMB3LYP\dmso\Veda\nq1a.out
diagonality factor = 53.06   <EPm> = 49.71
    IR    RAMAN   CM-1
 245.54  730.41  3538.10   s1 100
   3.93  204.17  3237.13   s6 93
  11.13  477.42  3233.43   s3 14   s5 76
   3.44  136.83  3229.53   s3 -78   s5 15
 262.17  212.10  1672.05   s16 61
 117.64  169.79  1669.31   s17 -64   s41 14
   9.66   60.78  1657.86   s19 -59   s44 10
 981.59 1079.26  1642.51   s18 -56
1030.99  315.40  1578.03   s37 40   s42 10
 185.95   27.40  1559.81   s37 20   s42 -37
  55.61   10.42  1535.81   s39 -53   s63 14
   4.91    5.16  1507.94   s20 -37   s40 44
  59.12   24.29  1504.96   s47 69   s76 -23
  14.09   29.85  1492.35   s46 -71   s75 22
  19.97    9.49  1487.58   s48 86
  17.93    4.37  1469.24   s21 -39   s43 -27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` doesn't return anything. The last line should just be:

```
vdf_big_list.append(vdf_s_lines_list)
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks, @Daniel!

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the return of `append` is None.
The first time you append, `vdf_big_list` get assigned as None.

Change code to

```
vdf_big_list.append(vdf_s_lines_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Yuvraj, you nailed it!